# Eclipse plugin: How to reuse opened external browser tab?

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, plugins

I am opening a new external browser tab from Java in my eclipse plugin project:

```
IWorkbenchBrowserSupport service = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getBrowserSupport();
service.createBrowser(IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.AS_EXTERNAL, "MyPreview", "MyPreview", "My Preview").openURL(url);
```

Unfortunately - as from the documentation - the external browser cannot be reused by giving a specific ID, so my parameters are ignored.

What could I do to avoid a new tab being opened each time the url changes?

Cheers